# ProjectM-pulseaudio streams and audio gain

Tags: c++, linux, qt, audio, pulseaudio

I'm using the [ProjectM](http://projectm.sourceforge.net/) audio visualizer on Linux. I'm running Ubuntu and Pulseaudio, and so I'm using the projectm-pulseaudio binary. Sadly it seems that development on ProjectM has ceased, and there's nothing else like it available for Linux that I can find.

I'm considering hacking the source to fix a couple of issues I have with it, but want to first get a feel for whether what I want to do is possible, since my C++ is very rusty, and my knowledge of Pulseaudio and qt is near zero.

ProjectM listens to the user's choice of one of the Pulseaudio output device monitors. There's a GUI to choose which you want, and I can make the same choice from the Pulseaudio volume control GUI. In my case, I can choose my video card's HDMI audio output, my motherboard's analogue audio output, or my motherboard's digital audio output. I'm using the last of those, since that's where my speakers are plugged in.

That's the major problem: it is listening to the mixed-down audio stream on its way out of the computer. I want it only to listen to the music stream; that is, a particular audio stream on its way into Pulseaudio. This would provide a couple of advantages:

- System sounds and sounds coming from other programs aren't part of the visualization.
- Sink volume is later in the chain and so doesn't affect the amplitude of ProjectM's input signal, and so changing my system volume (which I do rather than get up and tweak the speakers' volume directly) doesn't affect the visualization.

It seems that the volume of the music player (which is the same as the volume set on the music player's stream which I can access from the Pulseaudio volume control GUI) also affects the visualization, which is undesirable, but I'm hoping this is just a run-on effect, since turning down the music player volume obviously makes the amplitude lower by the time it gets to the sink, which is what ProjectM is listening to. What I really want is for ProjectM to get at the full volume audio signal before it is scaled down by any volume control.

Finally, there's one more hurdle in that I use replaygain, which scales down the volume of every song so that each album has an equivalent perceived volume. Replaygain by default targets 89dB, so I'm thinking it may be enough just to scale up each sample an appropriate amount once it gets in to ProjectM. That's probably the best I can do, since Pulse has no idea about replaygain, but I'd welcome other suggestions.

So the general question is whether this all sounds possible. In particular:

1. Is it possible to have an application (a modified version of ProjectM in this case) monitor a particular other application's Pulseaudio playback stream directly rather than it listening to an output device's monitor?
2. Is it possible to get the audio stream before it has been scaled by any volume controls? (Other than whatever scaling the music player application did for replaygain purposes.)
3. Will it be possible to reconnect to that stream if it is destroyed and recreated -- I don't know for instance if it'll still have some recognizable identifier each time. (It would be annoying to have to choose the stream each time playback is paused and resumed, or the music player is restarted.)

And finally, any tips or resources to look at would be appreciated. Or, if you have the skills to do this and would be interested in tackling it, I could offer a bounty.